# Declare Variable Character Length

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My table is shown below:

| Name | Depth | IsFile |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GMES9604U 1.10 770 CFM-2135.csv | 1 | 1 |

When I declare my variable, only part of the Name is stored:

```
declare @filename222 varchar(max)

SET @filename222 = CAST((
    SELECT Top 1 Name
    FROM #MyFiles  
) AS Varchar)

print(@filename222)

Result Messages:
GMES9604U 1.10 770 CFM-2135.cs
```

I was wondering how can I get the entire Name as my variable. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `... cast( ... AS varchar(MAX)) ...`?

Comment: You've missed the length off varchar in your cast.

Comment: And why do you even cast? Seems unnecessary here...

Comment: Use of TOP without an ORDER BY clause is generally a logical fault. That statement will retrieve one row - but the engine is free to retrieve any row. You might see a pattern based on load and usage but this can change at any time. Develop good habits.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casing to a `varchar`?  In SQL Server, you should never use string declarations without a length.  But the explicit cast is unnecessary.

Just use:

```
SELECT Top 1 @filename222 = Name
FROM #MyFiles  ;
```

The default length of `varchar` -- when used without a length -- depends on the context.  You could use an explicit `cast()`, but you would use `varchar(max)`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the name column in your table defined as?  Is it also `VARCHAR(MAX)` or is it defined as `VARCHAR(<some number>)`

If you already have the value in a table then the variable should be declared as the same data type and then you will never have a truncation issue.

Your issue is likely to be stemming from the fact that the default when no value is added for a `VARCHAR` declaration will be either 1 or 30 (see https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)